# How to reference "getSharedPreferences" from a static context that is not an Activity

Tags: android-studio

I'm in

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewholder>
```

When trying

```
SharedPreferences mySharedPrefData = getSharedPreferences("mySharedPrefData",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I get as an error:

```
Non-static method 'getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' cannot be referenced from a static context
```

I tried as alternatives

```
Context.getSharedPreferences("mySharedPrefData",MODE_PRIVATE)
```

and

```
this.getSharedPreferences("mySharedPrefData",MODE_PRIVATE)
```

and declaring `mySharedPrefData` as `static`

```
static SharedPreference mySharedPrefData
```

but all throw errors.

**Question**: How can I get data from `mySharedPrefData` into the class `MyAdapter`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Static way to get 'Context' in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to use the sharedPreferences you need to have the activity, so there's a lot of options here:

- if you're using fragments then you need activity to get applicationContext,
  you can get an activity by calling `requireActivity()` on your fragment object.
- then get a SharedPreferences reference to your data through this line of code.

```
Context context = requireActivity().getApplicationContext();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        "mySharedPrefData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

- then you can send this **sharedPref** reference through the adapter constructor when you initialize it.
  so your adapter constructor code should look like this :

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewholder> {
        SharedPreferences myShared ;
        public MyAdapter (SharedPreferences shared){
              myShared = shared ;
        }
}
```

which from now on you can use the myShared variable to access your shared preferences inside your adapter.

**N.B** : if you're not using fragments and initializing your adapter inside your main activity directly, then you can skip the `requireActivity` part and your shared preferences code will look like this instead

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        "mySharedPrefData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

#### Update

- since there's some confusion let me clarify that you should use the `getApplicationContext()` call inside your activity, assuming you initialize your adapter in `onCreate` method inside activity, then your **MainActivity** code might look like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       Context context = getApplicationContext();
       SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        "mySharedPrefData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       MyAdapter myAdapter = new myAdapter(sharedPref);
       ...
      }
}
```

**N.B** : three dots (...) means that I don't care about your code written here.

#### Update

- if you don't have the permission to edit the adapter constructor parameters then what about making a setter to it.

**MyAdapter.java**

```
    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewholder> {
            SharedPreferences myShared ;
            public MyAdapter (SomeOtherParameter){...}
            public void setMyShared(SharedPreferences shared){
                   myShared = shared ;    
            }
    }
```

- then after initializing your adapter, you set the shared Preferences to it

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       Context context = getApplicationContext();
       SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        "mySharedPrefData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       MyAdapter myAdapter = new myAdapter(SomeOtherParameter);
       myAdapter.setMyShared(sharedPref);
       ...
      }
}
```

**N.B** : if you used the code above then don't use the myShared object in any case in the adapter constructor to avoid NullPointerException

Comment: then just remove the requireActivity() call, and use `getApplicationContext()` directly, I edited the answer for you

Comment: Thanks,  but I get "Cannot resolve method 'getApplicationContext' in 'MyAdapter'  "

Comment: this method should be used inside an activity or using an activity object, since you didn't provide full code to how and where do you initialize your adapter, I can't but guess that you initialize it inside your activity.

Comment: please include more of your code to help me answer your question properly.

Comment: @Evenness, I've Updated my answer to clarify what I mean.

Comment: yes you should instantiate the sharedPreferences object where you instantiate the adapter but just before it so you can pass the object through the adapter constructor, like the code I included as an update. provided that you also updated the code of your adapter to include the constructor I wrote.

Comment: In MainActivity MyAdapter is already instantiated as "MyAdapter myAdapter = new myAdapter(arrayList). That arrayList contains the data that is to appear in the Recycler. So I cannot replace it with sharedPref.

Comment: well I don't know about that, you didn't include it in your code, but you can add the new parameter to the rest of parameters

Comment: Sorry for not including the code. Thought that would have been too much info. I'll try adding parameters as you suggest.

Comment: I've made another update to include the Shared Preferences object through a setter

Comment: I couldn't add sharedPref as an extra argument for MyAdapter() because the constructor of MyAdapter didn't allow for it. I changed the constructor to accept sharedPref (first had to add the field SharedPreference sharedPreferences to the MyAdapter class). IT WORKS. info of mySharedPref is now passed to myAdapter. Thank you so much for your extraordinary insight and time, Omar.

Comment: you are welcome and good luck in your app.

Comment: Thanks, but in the meantime, this question has got me blocked from asking questions on StackOverflow. Indefinitely :(